# Python: How to find out specific elements in a list with groups?

Tags: python, list, sorting, beautifulsoup

I have extracted the following list from a website and I was able to sort the list by price and item:

['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 1', '164.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '165.30EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '170.05EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '174.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR '],

['ITEM 2', '122.55EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '129.00EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 2', '132.05EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '136.80EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '139.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR '],

['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 3', '249.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '250.80EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '259.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '274.00EUR ']

...

Now I need to find out those elements, which include the 'Needed' AND are the cheapest ones. So for this example my needed output would be:

['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed'],

I really stuck on this, so any ideas on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: In particular, show the effort and coding progress you've made in attacking the problem.  How would you do this with pencil and paper?  How can you translate that to code?  You haven't bothered to extract prices from the middle strings, arrange the lists by product, or *anything* related to solving the problem.

Comment: Why should I extract prices from the middle strings? The list is already ranged by product and price using list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0,1)) and this is not related to the actual problem. The problem is to find out an element from a list if two conditions are met (element contains 'needed' and element is first place in group (groups in this case would be Item1; Item2; Item3)). So I neither see a "Can someone help me" style question nor that I haven't put effort in finding a solution before asking the question here.

Comment: I don't understand your output. Why it doesn't include "ITEM 2"? As a suggestion, you need to use if (len(element)==3) to filter the needed elements?

Comment: Ah -- if that order is *guaranteed*, that greatly simplifies the question!  You need only find the first occurrence of each item and check whether it's needed.

Comment: @user2341726 Because the lowest price from ITEM 2 is not marked with 'Needed'. Both conditions have to be true for the output (lowest price for the Item AND marked with  'needed').

Comment: @Prune Indeed, you pointed it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with fewer lines of code, depending on your level of Python programming and the readability level you want.  I've left it broken down to line-by-line steps.

```
order_list = [
    ['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 1', '164.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '165.30EUR '],
    ['ITEM 1', '170.05EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '174.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR '],

    ['ITEM 2', '122.55EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '129.00EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 2', '132.05EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 2', '136.80EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '139.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR '],

    ['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 3', '249.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '250.80EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 3', '259.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], 
    ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '274.00EUR ']
]

# Collect items only in a list
item_list = [line[0] for line in order_list]
# Collect only distinct items
product_list = set(item_list)
print "item list:", item_list
print "product list:", product_list

best_order = []

# Find the first (cheapest) occurence of each item;
#   See whether it's needed
for product in product_list:
    pos = item_list.index(product)
    line_item = order_list[pos]
    if 'Needed' in line_item:
        best_order.append(line_item)

print best_order
```

Output:

```
item list: ['ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 1', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3', 'ITEM 3']
product list: set(['ITEM 3', 'ITEM 2', 'ITEM 1'])
[['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can structure your lists as lists of lists:

```
l = [
        [['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 1', '164.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '165.30EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '170.05EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '174.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR '], ['ITEM 1', '179.00EUR ']],

        [['ITEM 2', '122.55EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '129.00EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 2', '132.05EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '136.80EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '139.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '144.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR '], ['ITEM 2', '154.00EUR ']],

        [['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed'], ['ITEM 3', '249.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '250.80EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '259.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '264.00EUR '], ['ITEM 3', '274.00EUR ']]
    ]

for item in l:
    try:
        if 'Needed' in item[0][2]:
            print item[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
['ITEM 1', '155.80EUR ', 'Needed']
['ITEM 3', '246.05EUR ', 'Needed']
```